# Stripe Implementation for subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

Trying to engineer a payment system with stripe that will bill the customer on a weekly basis. The customer can have as many documents but each one is charged weekly. So if the customer has 2 documents he would have 2 charges every week until he canceled both or one of them. I would like to be able to have a detailed email invoice too.

Would the best way to do this would just keep updating the subscription quantity every time one is added or deleted. Or is there a better way to do this.

AKA: I am new to online payments

Comment: This question is too broad. Please provide some basic code that you need help with including what language you are trying to do this with.

Comment: Once the user has a stripe id could then just change the relationship to the users and subscriptions table to hasMany and for every document created add another subscription to the same plan.

Comment: I am not sure how the subscriptions work but tthe user might buy one more document, but will it charge him fo a week on that one or just wait to the next week to charge him for 2 week.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create the plan on Stripe with a validity of 7 days and subscribed the customer to that plan on the recurring basis. So the customer will be charged automatically every week.
2. For the quantity, you can change the quantity of subscription on stripe or you can subscribe a customer to different weekly plans(If you have different documents rate)
3. For sending an email just enable invoice email from admin setting and  each time customer will pay an email will be sent.